Ask IHttpClientFactory to supply api key in query string
I need to call an external API that requires to send its key as a query string. The API has GET and POST endpoints. In both endpoints, there are no (currently) other parameters in queries
So, an example query should look like
https://example.com/service?key={key value}
I want to not add the query at all places where I call the client and rather configure it on the startup.
Normally, the examples I see put query strings as part of the route to the HTTP client with the question mark in between the route and query.
Is it possible to inject a key as a query string on startup without writing complicated extensions/logic?
I set up the injection like
    builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
    builder.Services.AddScoped<IMyService, MyService>();


and then consume it like
 public class MyService : IMyService
    {
        private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

        public MyService(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
        {
            _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
        }

        private HttpClient CreateClient() => _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
        
        public async Task<RouteDetails> GetRouteDetails(ICollection<Point> points)
        {
            var httpClient = CreateClient();
            var response = await httpClient.PostAsync($"/api/poi", new JsonContent(points));
...
        }
    }

I am looking for something easy to read and not too much extra code. I believe plenty APIs consume their access keys as a query string, so, there should be an out-of-the-box solution that I am missing.
I can also reference Refit if it is easier.
Edited: I put the wrong code to inject the service, it does not change the nature of the question, but as @PeterCsala suggested, I should not inject IHttpClientFactory into a typed client, I should have injected HttpClient.
I updated the code to the working version I used for the research.

I think it's in the Uri not the HttpClient => https://dotnetfiddle.net/3b2lG6 => or as Extension Method: https://dotnetfiddle.net/urbJHh

It is, but something has to add it to the Uri.

Step one is to create a DelegatingHandler that modifies the querystring. This answer demonstrates that. The most complicated part seems to be that the Uri type doesn't let you modify the query, so you have to create a whole new Uri that contains the original values and the new querystring.

Then do services.AddHttpClient<IMyService, MyService>().AddHttpMessageHandler<YourCustomHandler>();. I didn't make this an answe because most of what you need is in the other answer. But I didn't want to just mark it as a duplicate.

If you already have a typed client then why do want to do anything on the HttpClientFactory level??? Do the string concatenation inside the typed client. It is easy to read and maintain.

@PeterCsala It does not need to be at the factory level - but I wanted to do it at the setup level, so, I can call its multiple endpoints without needing to remember to add the key at every call, and I know we will not forget it when we implement a method to consume a new endpoint from the API.

@ScottHannen Thanks for the link. I do not want to use such or similar ways of manipulating query strings. I hoped I missed an out-of-the-box approach to this popular way of APIs consuming access keys. Since there does not seem to be one, I will write private methods for Post and Get calls inside the API caller class to get the route and parameters and they will add the key to the calls.

For some reason I thought there was a constraint that eliminated that. What you're describing sounds much better.

It seems there is no ready-made solution to my problem, so, I am adding the key to the route inside the client.
I am not checking for existing queries here as it is not needed for now, and I will add logic if/when required.
    private HttpClient CreateClient()
    {
        var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(_settings.BaseAddress);
        return httpClient;            
    }

    public async Task<RouteDetails> GetRouteDetails(ICollection<Point> points)
    {
        var response = await Post($"/api/poi", points);
...
    }

    private Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post(string route, object body)
    {
        var httpClient = CreateClient();
        return httpClient.PostAsync($"{route}?api-key={_settings.ApiKey}", JsonContent(body));
    }

    public StringContent JsonContent(object obj)
        => new (System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");


A similar approach was suggested by @PeterCsala in the comments
